# String.Format Same Code Different View

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting, currency, money-format

I have a code like this;

```
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[11].Text = String.Format("{0:c}", sumKV)
```

In my computer this code gives a result like that;

[image]

But when I upload this code to my virtual machine it looks like this;

[image]

**TL** means Turkish Liras. But I don't want to show the currency. I just want numbers.

I also don't want to change the formating of numbers. (Like 257.579,02)

How can I only delete **TL** in this code?

Comment: Gonul : Can you please let me know hoe you got TL ? I am trying to do other way, I want to print that TL symbol.

Comment: @62071072 It is my default currency symbol (for `tr-TR` culture). I didn't do anything special.

Comment: Gonul: Can you please tell me have used RegionInfo/ current culture to get TL ?

Comment: Gonul: Becasue currently my specific culture is (tr-Tr) but I am getting turkish symbol but not TL

Comment: Ganul :Hi is there any chance of posting a piece of code how you got TL as currency symbol ?

Comment: @62071072 Set your current region to `Turkey` and you can get `TL` with `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this:

```
var cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol = 
    (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[11].Text = 
            String.Format(cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol, "{0:c}", sumKV).Trim();
```

Background:
This will still keep the currency formatting for the current culture, it just removes the currency symbol.
You can save this special culture somewhere, so you don't have to create it every time you need to format your values.

**UPDATE:**

- Now it even compiles... ;-)
- Added a `Trim()`, because there is still a space after the formated number.

Comment: +1 Yes, it sounds a little bit hacky, but I'm afraid it's the only way to go

Comment: Laurent can you look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712356/gridview-trim-error-in-asp-net ?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to turn off the currency symbol entirely for the current thread:

```
private static NumberFormatInfo SetNoCurrencySymbol()
{
    CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    NumberFormatInfo LocalFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();

    NumberFormatInfo ret = culture.NumberFormat;

    LocalFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
    culture.NumberFormat = LocalFormat;

    // Add the culture to the current thread
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

    return ret;
}
```

That way you will change less code.  You can always change it back afterwards:

```
 NumberFormatInfo origNumberFormat  = SetNoCurrencySymbol();

 string x = String.Format("{0:c}", 55);

 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = origNumberFormat;

 string y = String.Format("{0:c}", 55);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using String.Format with a format string only, sumKV is formatted according to the UI Culture actually used in your application.

```
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[11].Text = String.Format("{0:c}", sumKV),
```

To get rid with currency symbol, use InvariantCulture in `String.Format` this way :

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:c}", sumKV);
```

Comment: I suggest, to *not* use this method, because it discards the formating for the current culture.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show currency then don't use the currency formatting code - {0:c}.
Perhaps try something like the following:

```
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[11].Text = String.Format("{0:G}", sumKV);
```

[See this article - String.Format doubles](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Comment: This doesn't take into account if the user configured his currency different from his normal numbers.