# Gridview Trim Error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, string-formatting, trim

This is my reference question; [String.Format Same Code Different View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562939/string-format-same-code-different-view)

When i try this code;

```
var cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol =
        (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[9].Text = String.Format(cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol, "{0:c}", sumMV).Trim();
```

I gettin an error like this;

[image]

How can i solve this problem?
Is it something wrong in my code?

Comment: Can't see where `sumMV` is defined, and if it is assigned any value

Comment: @ron-harlev here http://i.imgur.com/ae1rs.png

Comment: @Soner How about using **{0:N}**

Comment: Why would you need Trim() there? can't you just remove that and try

Comment: @V4Vendetta {0:N} doesn't work. Sorry!

Comment: @Subhash Dike Look at my reference question. unfortunately i delete trim but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Soner: Can you widen the Name column in your Watch window? It seems as if cultureWithoutCurrencySymbol is contained three times in that list, but twice it is null and once it is not null. That's not possible, so please make the Name column wide enough, so we can see the whole name. Additionally: Did you check that the following are not null: (1) `GridView1` (2) `GridView1.FooterRow` (3) `GridView1.FooterRow.Cells` (4) `GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[9]`. BTW: The trim is necessary, otherwise there will be a space after the formated number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want currency without symbol why don't simply use:

```
sumVM.ToString()
```

Comment: Please see the linked question. It doesn't take into account the possible user specific settings for currencies.

Comment: my point is don't format it as a currency because you just want a currency without a currency symbol => this mean a number only. So just format it as a number

Comment: Not a valid point in the following circumstance: The number indeed represents a currency and it is indicated elsewhere which currency. Formatting it as a normal number discards the user specific settings for currencies.